# How to read file in two or more levels zip file

Tags: r

the way I think is to do recursion. 
I wonder if there is better way to read file in two or more levels zip file. Thank you

for example:
I want to get file3.txt and file4.txt

```
file1.zip<br>
---file2.zip<br>
--- --- file3.txt<br>
--- --- file4.txt
```

Comment: You should post a link to a sample zip file for testing. AND the answer may be OS specific so you should include that information.

Comment: when you unzip a file, you can then grep for text ending in .zip, and if so, unizip again.